# Using subprocess from python 2.7 to 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using a program that runs a python 2.7 interpreter. I am trying to use this to subprocess a 3.10 python script outside of the program.

```
pro = r'c:\...\2p_python.py'
python_path = r'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe'
command = [python_path, pro]
return_code = subprocess.call(command)
```

I get syntax errors with this whether i use 'r' or '\' or both.

```
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'command'", ('C:/.../2p_opt.py', 85, 0, "command = ['C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe', 'c:\\...\\2p_python.py']\n"))
```

Comment: This seems to be a javarish message. Do you run Jython or anything else Java related?

Comment: i believe the interpreter may be jython actually

Comment: Are you able to run this command manually "C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe c:\\...\\2p_python.py". We can run python3 script from python2 easily. Please double check your path. You can test by try putting python3 and python2 script in same path to avoid path errors. Please share your python environment details, if this does not helps.